# MSBuild AspNetcompiler task

Tags: asp.net

I have a VB web application project built on vs 2003 and migrated to vs 2005. When i write a build script which looks like

Abc
c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Abc\

and execute the build script from vs2005 command prompt the build gets succeeded if i use the target Rbuild. But if i use Build as target the ASPNetcompiler is throwing errors which say "could not file or assembly or dependencies error:ASPPARSE. Could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

AspNetCompiler precompiles the code, so if there are any errors it is throwing it should be because of it was not able to compile the code.

I think you should try to resolve the errors.

The errors can be because you have referred to some usercontrol in the page and while compiling aspnetcompiler is not able to recognize the usercontrol.

The point to be noted here is that this errors will be thrown in runtime, however aspnetcompiler throws this errors while compiling itself to save time.

Comment: But the project is building successfully if am using msbuild task to build the project.The problem only occurs when the aspnetcompiler task is getting executed.

Comment: Yes the project will build properly, however compiling is different than building. Compiler actually tries to bind all the events of aspx and cs validating it(one of the function of compiler), however the build does not do that.